# Automate opening and formatting of csv file in unix

Tags: excel, unix, csv, spreadsheet, openoffice.org

My requirement is as follows:

1. Open an input csv file in spreadsheet in unix (like ooffice)
2. Post process the excel for following requirements:

   - Post process a column such that fields with number less that 0 appear as red
   - Put filters on top of each relevant columns (As we can do in Microsoft excel)
   - save the file in .xls (or any other format) such that when opened in microsoft excel, the data formatting is not lost.

The above automation requirement is part of my flow. Though I am familiar with scripting, I have never worked on such requirement.
Will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using [csv2odf](http://csv2odf.sf.net) that should get the result you want:

Create a spreadsheet template in Excel or OpenOffice with these specifications:

1. Insert column titles with the same number of columns as the csv.  (If you want to use titles from the csv file, add the -H option to the command below.)
2. Add one sample row of data.  Use dummy numbers where numbers will go and dummy text where text will go.  Format the text/numbers however you want, including conditional formatting to make negative numbers red.
3. Save the template as xlsx or ods (xls will not work).

Run this command:

```
csv2odf yourdata.csv yourtemplate.xlsx output.xlsx
```

Your data will be inserted into the template and the formatting will be duplicated on each row.

Comment: Are you aware of any other application like csv2odf